# Error upgrading 1.9.2p180 to 1.9.3 with RVM on Lion

Tags: rvm, osx-lion, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9.2

I'm getting this error when running the following command:

```
$ rvm upgrade 1.9.2-p180 1.9.3-p0
Are you sure you wish to upgrade from ruby-1.9.2-p180 to     ruby-1.9.3-p0? (Y/n): Y
Installing new ruby ruby-1.9.3-p0
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/ericjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #extracted to /Users/ericjones/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 (already extracted)
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/ericjones/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/ericjones/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/ericjones/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /Users/ericjones/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/ericjones/.rvm/usr
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #compiling 
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/ericjones/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/make.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
ERROR: Unable to install ruby ruby-1.9.3-p0.         Please install it manually to continue.
```

When i tail the log i get the following output:

```
installing default stringio libraries
installing default strscan libraries
installing default syck libraries
installing default syslog libraries
linking shared-object tcltklib.bundle
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/tk/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Any ideas on how to move forward?

Answer (score 9):

This fixed it for me.

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
ln -s /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib /usr/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
```

kept my XCode 4.2 as well...

found at this blog:
http://hello.keewooi.com/ruby-1-9-3-preview-1-available-now/

Answer (score 0):

From the message it looks like your iconv isn't compiled for x86_64.

Check `rvm notes` and `rvm requirements` to see if they shed more light on the problem.

Comment: well i looked into it and this is the only lines which throw flags in rvm requirements...

'** Lion Users: Xcode Version 4.2.x for OS X Lion works only for ruby 1.9.3-p0 (or higher). It currently fails to build several other rubies and gems, as well as several Homebrew and Macports packages. Xcode Version 4.1 (4B110) works.'

Problem is i need the latest XCode. i uninstall RVM completely thinking that would fix it but i'm still getting the same error.